# Javascript Buy SDK - Error: Not Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, shopify

I'm trying to retrieve products from my Shopify store with this code, a near copy/paste of [the examples page](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/examples/) for the Javascript Buy SDK:

```
$(function() {
  var shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
    accessToken: '4b4e3d4bba63039f2d51db94c2e79a46',
    domain: 'squatch-air-clutches-test.myshopify.com',
    appId: '6'
  });

  shopClient.fetchQueryProducts({
    collection_id: 1397227547
  }).then(function(products) {
    $('.test').append(JSON.stringify(products));
  });

  shopClient.fetchProduct('46656520219').then(function(product) {
    $('.test').append(JSON.stringify(product));
  });

});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/3njvk45z/1/)

The `buildClient` command seems to complete successfully, however I get a console error with the next two commands: `Error: Not Found`. I assume this refers to the product not able to be found, but I am sure both the product and the collection ids are correct. And I am also sure that I have `read access` enabled for "products, variants, and collections" for my private app. **Would there be any other reason I am getting this error, and if so, what's a solution?**

Comment: The documentation says: _"Note: You will need to publish the product/collection you wish to interact with to the “Buy Button” channel in Shopify."_, have you done this?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I hadn't, but I went ahead and did. Same results, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. The App ID was incorrect. I needed to go to `/admin/settings/storefront_access_tokens` and grab the correct ID for my sales channel. I'm disappointed that it was so difficult to find though - the documentation on this seems convoluted.